# Java: how to locate an element via xpath string on org.w3c.dom.document

Tags: java, dom, xpath

How do you quickly locate element/elements via xpath string on a given org.w3c.dom.document? there seems to be no `FindElementsByXpath()` method. For example

```
/html/body/p/div[3]/a
```

I found that recursively iterating through all the child node levels to be quite slow when there are lot of elements of same name. Any suggestions?

I cannot use any parser or library, must work with w3c dom document only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495758/detect-hyperlink-hover-in-webview-and-print-the-link

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this:

```
//obtain Document somehow, doesn't matter how
DocumentBuilder b = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = b.parse(new FileInputStream("page.html"));

//Evaluate XPath against Document itself
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/html/body/p/div[3]/a",
        doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
    Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);
}
```

With the following `page.html` file:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div><a>link</a></div>
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my code example `doc` is of `org.w3c.dom.Document` type. If you already have an instance of `Document`, just use two last lines of my code and that's it! P.S.: Why the downvote?

Comment: this returns text. I need domelement or domelements.

Comment: See my edit (introduction of `XPathConstants.NODESET` parameter) - now it returns `NodeList`. Also have a look at other constants as well.

Comment: @Tomasz Nukiewicz , can you please look into my implementation. I know I am not the the questioner and itz a different question, but I took the reference from your answer, so I hope u can help me,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389376/creating-a-xml-tree-in-java-and-convert-it-to-json-object

Comment: I think you don't need to do `doc.getDocumentElement()`, you should be able to run the xpath on `org.w3c.dom.Document` type directly.