# java xml retrieve named parameter

Tags: java, xml

```
<root>
<program name="SomeProgramName">
    <params>
        <param name='name'>test</param>
        <param name='name2'>test2</param>
    </params>
</program>
</root>
```

I have the above xml doc. I need to change the value of test to a new value

I read in the xml doc as

```
String xmlfile = "path\\to\\file.xml"
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlfile);

//get the params element
Node params = doc.getElementsByTagName("params").item(0);

//get a list of nodes in the params element
NodeList param = params.getChildNodes();
```

This is where I am stuck. I can't find a method to set the value of one of the param elements by the "name"

I'm using java 1.7

Comment: I suggest using an XPath query on it.  Syntax would be something like `/root/program/params/param[@name='name2']`.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538883/java-how-to-locate-an-element-via-xpath-string-on-org-w3c-dom-document) for the xpath setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  NodeList params = doc.getElementsByTagName("param");
  for (int i = 0; i < params.getLength(); i++)
  {
     if (params.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue().equals("name2"))
     {
        // do smth with element <param name='name2'>test2</param>
        // that is params.item(i) in current context
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to type each Node to type [Element](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) to be able to set the text and attributes.  You might want to look at [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/), which simplifies things like this.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xmlfile = "src/forum17753835/file.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(xmlfile);

        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
        Element element = (Element) xpath.evaluate("/root/program/params/param[@name='name2']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(element.getTextContent());
    }

}
```

Comment: xpath looks interesting. I will look into this solution