# Find only the first groups XML (DOM)

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I have the following XML structure:

```
<doc>
    <group name="name1">
        <group name="subname1">
            <item att="att1"/>
        </group>
        <group name="subname3">
            <item att="att3"/>
        </group>
    </group>
    <group name="name2">
        <group name="subname2">
            <item att="att2"/>
        </group>
    </group>
</doc>
```

If I'm using `dom.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("group")` then I get all "group" of my xmlfile (name1, subname1, subname3,.......).

How to find only the first groups(name1 and name2)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dom.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("group")[0];
```

Comment: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to NodeList"

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("doc");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
{                   
      Node node = nodeList.item(i); 

      if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
      {
           Element e = (Element) node;
           NodeList resultNodeList = e.getElementsByTagName("group");
           int resultNodeListSize = resultNodeList.getLength();
           for(int j = 0 ; j < resultNodeListSize ; j++ )
           {
                 Node resultNode = resultNodeList.item(j);
                 Element fstElmnt1 = (Element) resultNode.getParentNode();
                 Log.v("name--", ""+ ( fstElmnt1.getAttribute("name")));
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538883/java-how-to-locate-an-element-via-xpath-string-on-org-w3c-dom-document) and use an XPath expression like this `/doc/group/@name = 'name1' or /doc/group/@name = 'name2'` to only retrieve groups with a set attribute-field 'name' which equals either `name1` or `name2`.

If you want to extract only the group tags which are children of `doc` the XPath expression shortens to `/doc/group`. This will also retrieve `<group name="name3">` and `<group name="name4">` automatically if they are defined as children of `<doc>` within your XML.