# JAVA DOM: Delete parent tag if child tag has specified value

Tags: java, xml, dom, methods, tags

I'm doing a simple Java DOM app for car renting. I have a `<car>` tag that contains `<id>` tag, I'm trying to make a method that deletes the `<car>` tag by specifying the value of the `<id>` tag. I've tried thinking of a solution and looked at similar questions but haven't figured it out. Here's structure of my XML document:

```
<parking>
<car>
    <id>1</id>
</car>
<car>
    <id>2</id>
</car>
<car>
    <id>3</id>
</car>
<car>
    <id>4</id>
</car></parking>
```

Comment: Use XPath to select the car by it's id `/parking/car[id=3]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538883/java-how-to-locate-an-element-via-xpath-string-on-org-w3c-dom-document

Comment: I've tried different stuff, here's the version of my method that seems closest to truth, but doesn't work https://pastebin.com/UmEjTcUM

Could you fix it please? I feel like I'm close to figuring it out